# Trying to install an Astrophysics-Code (HARM) but having problem running the "make" command

Tags: compiling, gcc, make

This is the Guide to the Installation:

https://github.com/atchekho/harmpi/blob/master/tutorial.md

I get this result on `make clean` :

```
/bin/rm -f *.o *.il
/bin/rm -f harm image_interp
```

but this, when I try to `make`:

```
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:109: recipe for target 'harm' failed
make: *** [harm] Error 1
```

I have installed Open-MPI using this guide http://lsi.ugr.es/jmantas/pdp/ayuda/datos/instalaciones/Install_OpenMPI_en.pdf

I COULDN'T Install `libopenmpi-dbg` and I installed `libopenmpi2` instead of `libopenmpi1.3`

Don't know if that mattered

and I have this result on GCC-Version:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Is your first link correct? it appears to be about OpenMPI not HARM

Comment: `DSO missing from command line` usually means there should be a `-lxxx` (in this case, `-lm`) on the linker command line but it's missing

Comment: @steeldriver I added it. You were right, I'm really sry. How do I add this -lm ?

Comment: Try `make EXTRALIBS=-lm`

Comment: @steeldriver It runs and the second time I run it, is : image_interp.c: In function ‘main’:
image_interp.c:111:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fread’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   fread(&oldimage[i][j], sizeof(unsigned char), 1, stdin) ;

Comment: You can usually ignore warnings (they're really meant for the software's developers, rather than its users) - in this case, it's just highlighting some lazy programming practice i.e. not checking that `fread` succeeded in reading the expected number of items

Comment: @steeldriver so its the right answer :) Wanna post it so I can upvote?

Comment: Thanks - answer posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

```
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

means that the linker can't find symbols from the standard math library: it knows where they should be, and expected a linker directive `-lm` on the command line, but didn't find one.

If you look at the provided `makefile`, you can see there's some back-and-forth about the appropriate linker flags when building with MPI:

```
ifeq ($(USEMPI),1)
EXTRALIBS= #-lm #-lmpi
EXTRACCFLAGS=-DMPI
CC=mpicc #/usr/local/bin/mpicc
else
EXTRALIBS = -lm
EXTRACCFLAGS =
endif
```

At some point, the software's author must have decided that linking `libm` was not necessary in this case. You can override that decision on the command line as follows

```
make EXTRALIBS=-lm
```

There will likely be a number of compiler warnings which you may ignore.